# opening port for tomcat on centos server using iptables?

Tags: linux, centos, iptables, tomcat

i have added a rule in iptables in my server like this.

```
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 8005 -j ACCEPT
```

allowing port 8005. 
when run this command `netstat -plunt` it shows that port 8005 is opened. result is as under

```
tcp        0      127.0.0.1:8005                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      22128/java
```

i have saved iptables, restarted services for iptables and tomcat5. but still i am unable to access tomcat5 from browser.

what might be the issue?

i have configured port `8005` for tomcat in `server.xml`
my `iptables -L -nv` out put is as attached
[image]

connector port config is as under

```
<Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
```

Comment: Do you have a rule that allows `RELATED` and `ESTABLISHED` traffic ?  You might want to add the output of `iptables -L -nv` to your question.  Since you're only listening on localhost, I'm curious, how are you testing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The part `127.0.0.1:8005` from `netstat` output indicates that your server is listening on the loop address `127.0.0.1` which means you can connect only locally to the port 8005.

If you want to access the service remotely from another machine, you need to change the tomcat configuration to allow it listen on all interfaces or on a specific interface.

Comment: Khaled thanks, you are right. can you please help me , how can i allow tomcat to be accessed from other interfaces?

Comment: It's not so much "allowing it to be accessed from" as "telling it to listen on".  Somewhere in the Tomcat configuration it will say something like "Listen 127.0.0.1:8005".  You should change this to the IP address on your other interface.  (I haven't touched Tomcat in years so that configuration option might be completely different in reality.)

Comment: @Asghar: You need to change the connector in `server.xml` file.

Comment: @Khaled i have edited my question and added configuration for connector in server.xml , is it good?

Comment: @Asghar: Try to add the `address` attribute and set to `0.0.0.0`.

Comment: I don't see port 8005 in your server.xml.

Comment: @Asghar: Maybe, you did not edit the right connector.

Comment: @ladadadada edited the question with 8005 port

Comment: i have edited /etc/tomcat5/server.xml file. and connector in it.